# Applying a force on a rigid body on a certain point

Tags: forces, rigid-body-dynamics

I have a rigid body with an origin point (at the center of mass).

I want to apply a force on a certain point.

So what is the force applied to the origin of this rigid body?

Description image:

[image: description image]

Note: I don't want the moment of torque.

More explanation:

Assume $p$ is a point in the space of a rigid body.

So if we had a force $\vec F_{p}$ at a point $p$, how can we get the $\vec F_{center}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any force applied to any part of a rigid object acts on the object as a whole. So if you were to place a directional force meter at the center of the object (or at any other point on the object), it would register the force $\vec{F}_p$.

Comment: but if it wasn't in the center , it will cause a torque . how does the energy still the same as if without torque ?

Comment: Because the rotation imparted by the force means that it takes more work to push the body obliquely.

Comment: could you explain more please ?